# Program compiles, but doesn't return results. Quadratic equation program that utilizes methods and printf()

Tags: java

i'm new to Java and i'm hoping this is an easy fix. I have a program that i'm sure would work but i'm receiving no proper calculations. Some requirements are utilizing a method that solves for a discriminant, and utilizing printf to get precise calculations. Anyone with experience know what i'm doing wrong? I have a feeling it has to do with the return value. Thank you for your time and patience. Hope to hear from everyone soon.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuadraticSolver {
 public static double discriminant(double a, double b, double c){
 double discriminant;
 double root1;
 double root2;
 double imaginary;
 discriminant = (b*b - 4*a*c); 
 
 if (discriminant > 0){
     
     root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)/(2*a));
     root2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant)/(2*a));
     
      System.out.println("The quadratic equation has two real solutions: ");
      System.out.printf("x = %.4f" ,root1);
      System.out.printf(" + %.4f%n" , root2);

 } else if (discriminant == 0) {
      root1 = (-b/(2*a));
      
      System.out.println("The quadratic equation has one real solution:");
      System.out.printf("x = %.4f" ,root1);

 } else if (discriminant < 0) {
     root1 = root2 = -b / (2 * a);
     imaginary = Math.sqrt(-discriminant) / (2 * a);
      System.out.println("The quadratic equation has two complex solutions: ");
      System.out.printf("x = %.4f" ,root1);
      System.out.printf(" + %.4f" ,imaginary);
      System.out.println("i");
      System.out.printf("x = %.4f" ,root2);
      System.out.printf("  %.4f" ,imaginary);
      System.out.println("i");

 } else {
     System.out.println("Wow, how did you do that?");

      
 }
 return discriminant;
 }
     
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double a, b, c, x;
        
        System.out.println("This program is designed to solve a quadratic equation in standard form");
        System.out.println("a*x^2 + b*x + c = 0 ");
        System.out.println("Please enter a value for each following variable:");
        System.out.println("Quadratic coefficient a: ");
        a = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Linear coefficient b: ");
        b = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Constant c: ");
        c = in.nextInt();
        
        if (a == 0){
        
        System.out.println("Hey don't make a = 0, that's not cool man.");
        
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hi Javier - Please try adding more context to your question and the stack trace of the error you're getting. In case you want to get some tips on how to get higher chances to get this question answer please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call the function discriminant at the end of your main function.

```
QuadraticSolver.discriminant(a, b, c);
```

Comment: Hell yeah thanks marc, I didn't know how to call the function back. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome Javier. Please accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed calling the method discriminant(...)
You can do something like:

```
if (a == 0) {
    System.out.println("Hey don't make a = 0, that's not cool man.");
    return;
} else {
    discriminant(a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help as well Dexter, appreciate y'all